# How to organize images in directory into classes dependent on dataframe column values?

Tags: python, bash, dataframe

I have a directory of images from [this kaggle comp](https://www.kaggle.com/c/petfinder-adoption-prediction/data). Images with the same animal in them have the same prefix in their name, and then followed by `-{num}` where num is the number image of that specific animal.

So:

```
abc-1.jpg
abc-2.jpg
def-1.jpg
...
abg-1.jpg
abg-2.jpg
abg-3.jpg
poc-1.jpg
qrs-1.jpg
```

So as you can see there can be different numbers of images of each.

Then I have a dataframe (or .csv) that has 1 column which is the prefix of each animal's filename and another column which is a class `[0,1,2,3,4,5]`, and a final column that is the number of images that exist for each animal

*UPDATE: assume we already have the number of images of each animal*

```
animal    class     num_images
abc        0            2
def        0            1
abg        2            3
poc        1            1
qrs        4            1
```

I want to organize the images into directories: `dir0, dir1, dir2, dir3, dir4, dir5`, based on the class that image corresponds with.

Here's one way I imagine doing this task: (definitely not the best way)
I was able to get bash command that organizes the images into directories based on the prefix: `for file in *.jpg; do mkdir -p -- "${file%%-*}" && mv -- "$file" "${file%%-*}"; done`

Then somehow looping through each animal prefix in the dataframe and appending the corresponding `{num}`'s and placing them in a directory named: `dir` + `{class}`

Comment: abc and def have different classes I am sure this is a typo

Comment: @Inder the class is not the number of images, it is something totally different. Since abc and def have the same class, all of `abc-1`, `abc-2`, and `def-1` would all go into `dir0`

Comment: I don't understand why you keep mentioning the number of images. If I understand correctly, you only want to *move* the files to directories based on their category. Why would you need the number of images for that?

Comment: @Socowi I was just thinking because each filename has the animal code appended with a `-` and `{num}` and I thought you'd have to move each file separtely into each dir. But I could imagine if you are able to grab just the prefix, then yes it would be much easier to just move every file with that prefix into the corresponding directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Basic Command

This answer uses the same approach as [Inder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54935687/6770384) but inside a single `awk` command which *could* be faster. Not that it would matter in this case... Here we assume a file as given in your example as input, see next section for alternative input formats.

```
awk 'NR>1 { system("mkdir -p dir"$2"; mv "$1"-* dir"$2) }' dataframe.csv
```

In your example this executes the following `bash` commands:

```
mkdir -p dir0
mv abc-* dir0
mkdir -p dir0
mv def-* dir0
mkdir -p dir2
mv abg-* dir2
mkdir -p dir1
mv poc-* dir1
mkdir -p dir4
mv qrs-* dir4
```

The `-p` option of `mkdir` won't cause an error if the directory already exists. With `mv abc-* dir0` we move all files starting with `abc-` into the directory `dir0`.

#### Using Your Actual Input Format

From the comments it seems that your actual file has a different format then the example you showed us. The example had columns separated by whitespace

```
animal    class
abc        0
def        0
abg        2
...
```

but your actual file seems to be a real csv with columns separated by commas. Furthermore, the file seems to have windows line endings (`\r\n` instead of `\n`).

```
animal,class\r
abc,0\r
def,0\r
abg,2\r
...
```

You can use this format by adapting `awk`'s special variables `FS` (for field separator) and `RS` (for record separator):

```
awk -F, -v RS='\r?\n' 'NR>1 { system("mkdir -p dir"$2"; mv "$1"-* dir"$2) }' dataframe.csv
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error here as I am with @Inder, It seems it's grabbing both columns for $1 and $2, based on this error message: `mv: rename edb920079,1\r-* to dir/edb920079,1\r-*: No such file or directory.` `edb920079,1` seems to be the first two columns in the csv file and is getting grabbed for both $1 and $2

Comment: So here's what ended up working: `awk -F',' 'NR>1 { system("mkdir -p dir"$2"; mv "$1"-* dir"$2) }' dataframe.csv`

Comment: @jchaykow Ah, now I get what went wrong. You said csv (comma separated) but posted a tsv (tab, or at least whitespace, separated) file. Everyone here assumed that the columns are separated by whitespace as in the example. Also, your file seems to have windows line endings, you may want to account for that too. At the moment your directory names could contain an (invisible) `\r`. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick, with valuable inputs from @Socowi:

```
while read -r f1 f2 #store values of each row for first column and second
do

    mkdir "dir${f2}" #makes directory with the name
    mv ${f1}.* "dir${f2}/" #moves all the files with the class name to that directory 

done < <(tail +2 file.csv) #reads file line by line except first
```

P.S file.csv is the file that contain the classes and their names etc, number of files doesn't really matter.

Comment: should f1 and f2 be reversed in the `mv` line? I'm getting `mv: rename .. to 5f2edae7c,4\r/..: Invalid argument`

Comment: For some reason I can't get this to work. It seems it's grabbing both columns for f1 and f2, based on this error message: `mv: rename edb920079,1\r-* to dir/edb920079,1\r-*: No such file or directory`. `edb920079,1` seems to be the first two columns in the csv file

Answer (score 0):

Often, when I'm writing a moderately complex script -- or a script which has to iterate correctly a large number of times -- I don't write a script that does the work, I write a script that outputs a sequence of commands that will do the work.  That way, I can take a moment to review the script's output, and determine whether the command sequence it generated looks reasonable.  Since it's just shell commands, I can also include comments in the script output, to "show my work" and confirm that the actions the script is taking are based on sound logic.

Inder's solution is indeed clever, that a wildcard will suffice.  While he was writing that, I was writing this:

Let the dirN directories be created already, the class table be in file `class`, and the list of files to be moved in file `files`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# read in the class table:

eval $(
tail +2 classes |\
while read PREF CLASS
do
        echo X$PREF=$CLASS\;
done
)

# now iterate through the filenames:

while read FILE
do
        GROUP=${FILE%%-*}
        CLASS="X${GROUP}"
        printf '# file "%s" is group "%s", which is class "%s"\n' "$FILE" "$GROUP" "${!CLASS}"
        printf 'mv -vi "%s" "dir%s"\n' "$FILE" "${!CLASS}"
done < files
```

The output of that script is:

```
$ ./foo.sh
# file "abc-1.jpg" is group "abc", which is class "0"
mv -vi "abc-1.jpg" "dir0"
# file "abc-2.jpg" is group "abc", which is class "0"
mv -vi "abc-2.jpg" "dir0"
# file "def-1.jpg" is group "def", which is class "0"
mv -vi "def-1.jpg" "dir0"
# file "abg-1.jpg" is group "abg", which is class "2"
mv -vi "abg-1.jpg" "dir2"
# file "abg-2.jpg" is group "abg", which is class "2"
mv -vi "abg-2.jpg" "dir2"
# file "abg-3.jpg" is group "abg", which is class "2"
mv -vi "abg-3.jpg" "dir2"
# file "poc-1.jpg" is group "poc", which is class "1"
mv -vi "poc-1.jpg" "dir1"
# file "qrs-1.jpg" is group "qrs", which is class "4"
mv -vi "qrs-1.jpg" "dir4"
```

If those commands look okay, then run the script again and pipe the output to bash:

```
$ ./foo.sh  | bash
abc-1.jpg -> dir0/abc-1.jpg
abc-2.jpg -> dir0/abc-2.jpg
def-1.jpg -> dir0/def-1.jpg
abg-1.jpg -> dir2/abg-1.jpg
abg-2.jpg -> dir2/abg-2.jpg
abg-3.jpg -> dir2/abg-3.jpg
poc-1.jpg -> dir1/poc-1.jpg
qrs-1.jpg -> dir4/qrs-1.jpg
```

Building a "meta-script" in this fashion allows one to check one's work before performing a possibly not-quite-correct action thousands of times.  Granted, however, it may not be practical in cases where there are not thousands but millions or billions of iterations.  Still, if one uses this technique on a small sub-sample of a mammoth dataset, it can be a very useful technique to debug your script logic with little or no downside to having an error in your script.  Just give the script output a very careful review before you pipe it into a live bash shell.

Comment: Seems awfully convoluted and probably won't work on the actual dataset. `${FILE:0:3}` looks like you are assuming that the prefixes are always three characters long, but the actual dataset (see link in OP's question) uses prefixes of a different length. Instead of using `eval ... X$PREF=$CLASS` you might want to have a look at associative arrays.

Comment: Thanks. Edited to remove the 3-character assumption.